# Getting and observing/listening androd run-time permissions result back into application

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-permissions

`Code`

```
 private void pickPermissions(){

   showDialog("", "You have denied some necessary permissions permanently"
                    + " We will direct you to [Settings] screen, Turn on all permissions at [Settings] -> [Permissions].",
            "Go To Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //Todo: open setting screen for permission result
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                    //finish();
                }
            }, "No, Close App", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            },false);

}
```

please guide me how to know whether user granted all permissions or not in my app using onActivityResult()? and is there any way to get the user back(automatically) to the app from settings screen once they grant all the permissions in app settings screen, without them pressing back button?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ContextCompat#checkSelfPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) method you can get the state of permission grant for each permission you requested individually, if any of them aren't granted then you can take the user to the settings screen as your code does.

About checking whether the user has granted the permissions after that, you can try hooking up the permission check in the [onResume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity#onResume()) method and going through the dialog flow again.

Comment: How to hookup permission check at onResume(). When android request for permissions first time, the activity goes into onPause() which intern call onResume() as soon as we respond to the permissions request. this way it will be an infinite loop. Plus what is the use case of onActivityResult() here?

Comment: The same ContextCompat call will work in onResume as well. onActivityResult is only fired when the activity is resumed after a request made through something like requestPermissions, as opposed to onResume which is always called when resuming.